# Prove or disprove: $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am trying to determine whether the following statement is true or false:

Let $f(x)$ be a function with the following properties:

1. $f$ is unbounded.
2. $f(n) = 0$ for every $ n \in $ {$1, 2,3,...$}.

Prove or disprove:

$f$ is not uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty]$

I belive this statement must be true.

If $f(n) = 0$ for very natural $n$, and $f$ is unbounded, Then $f(x)$ slope is getting more steeper and steeper as $x$ grows.

For example we can take a look at $f(x) = xsinx$ which is not uniformly continious:

[image]

Yet, I am not so sure how to formally prove this statement.

Any hints will be appericiated.

Comment: I just learned about uniform continuity myself so I don’t know how to do this either. I wonder if you can do a proof by contradiction and find an $\epsilon$ that makes the definition of uniform continuity fail?

Comment: @blakedylanmusic I think a proof by contradiction is the way to go, But I am struggling with it.

Comment: What happens if $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge 0$ while $f(x)=x\sin(x)$ for $x<0$?

Comment: @Henry: I am sure it is it is implicitly assumed that the function is defined on $[1, \infty)$. It should have been written, though.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - possibly.  Also the illustrative function should probably have been something like $x \sin(\pi x)$ to meet the $f(n)=0$ requirement

Answer (score 2):

Assume it was uniformly continuous.  Pick an $\epsilon$,  say $\epsilon=1$.   Then there exists a $\delta>0$  such that $\forall x_1,x_2$ such that $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$,  $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<1$.    now you can cross the distance from $n$ to $n+1$ in finitely many $\delta$ steps,  which means the growth between each two is bound to that many steps,  which contradicts the function being unbounded